# Software recommendation for sound effects creation and editing

Tags: windows-7, audio, game-development

I am going to develop my own games soon.
So, I want to know if there is any software to make sound effects mainly from scratch or modify from recording.

My state :-

1. FMOD only provides for sound editing and not creation from scratch
   (and I am using libGDX on Android Studio...I can't figure out a way to connect FL studio with libGDX).
2. I need a software to create/edit sound effects and be able to record or save them to a file.
3. I am ready to gain advanced knowledge of it if that's what it takes...
4. I am not sure about FL studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Mac user, you can use GarageBand, which is free for the basic version, but costs $4.99 USD for more instruments, effects, and lessons. Another option would be to buy Logic Pro X for a massive $244.11 USD. It comes with far more sound mixing features and fine tuning tools for a professional audio experience.

If you use Windows too, you can get Ableton Live 9 Suite for a hefty  $594.30 USD. Just like with Logic Pro X, it allows fine tuning of audio and powerful sound mixing. Another option would be Fruity Loops Studio. For the producer edition, it would cost $199.00 USD, which is a somewhat reasonable cost for a true audio experience in comparison to other programs. Overall, if you're willing to pay a bigger price, you will end up with high-level software for only true audiophiles and sound enthusiasts.